# ValidationError item in the log

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

```
const student  = db.define('student',{ //This is a model 
    name: {
        type: datatype.STRING(40),
        allowNull: false
    },
    age:{
            type: datatype.INTEGER(2),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: -1
        }
    
})

const task = async()=>{
    try{
        await db.sync()
        .then(()=> console.log("Connection Established"))
        .catch((err)=> console.log(err))

        //Insert a Student
        for(let i=0;i<30;i++){
            await student.create({
                name: (['Tom','Dick','Van Dijk','Muller','Virat','Allison'])[parseInt(Math.random()*10)],
                age: 10 * parseInt(Math.random()*10)
            })
        }
        
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
}

task();
```

For Executing this I am getting an error like this:
ValidationErrorItem {
message: 'student.name cannot be null',
type: 'notNull Violation',
path: 'name',
value: null,
origin: 'CORE',
instance: [student],
validatorKey: 'is_null',
validatorName: null,
validatorArgs: []
}

student is a table that is a model and task is a function that is inserting elements into it.

Answer (score 0):

The output number of `parseInt(Math.random()*10)` is from `0` to `<=9`. But the length of `['Tom','Dick','Van Dijk','Muller','Virat','Allison']` is `6`. So there maybe an `undefined` value if the index greater than `5`. The `name` field in sequelize schema has `allowNull: false` constraint. The `undefined` value violates the `NOT NULL` constraint. That's why you got the validation error.

You should modify it like this:

```js
parseInt(Math.random() * 6)
```

It will give you a number from `0` to `<=5`.